# Get build.xml from Google Play Service lib

Tags: android, netbeans, ant, google-play-services

How to get build.xml from Google Play Service lib?
Running   **android update project -p "C:\google-play-services_lib"** fails
Nothing in this folder is not created

If it is run for the usual android project -  build.xml appears
but with Google Play Service - no

Answer (score 0):

If running `android update project --path` on the google_play_services directory doesn't work, create build.xml file.

Go to the system SK Directory then change the target as needed:

```
$SDK_HOME/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib and run "android update project -p ./ --target 20"
```

Another workaround is to delete google_play_services and get a fresh copy from the Android SDK manager.

Comment: I'll do it   "android update project -p ./ --target 20" , but nothing is created